# Real time keypress event assembly x86 TASM

Tags: assembly, interrupt, tasm, dosbox

I'm trying to make a Snake game in TASM, but I have a problem; I can't seem to figure out how to keep the Snake moving while waiting for a keypress, because ah = 0 and int 16h is stopping the Snake and waiting for a keypress.
Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Why are you programming a DOS game in 2017?

Comment: You can use polling in a loop, or an interrupt handler.

Comment: @zwol School...

Comment: OK, why do schools still teach 16-bit DOS assembly programming in 2017? (I suppose there might still be a use for it as an optional elective...)

Comment: @zwol 16-bit DOS programming is more instructive that you may think :) That's the same with math: we teach fractions in grade schools and not equivalency classes and integrity domains.

Comment: All it takes is using function AH=01h (instead of AH=00h) from the same interrupt `int 16h`. That's the one that doesn't stop. It only does a brief check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int 21h`, `ah=0BH`, to check if a key was pressed, without stopping the program, example :

```
game:
;CHECK IF KEY WAS PRESSED.
  mov ah, 0bh
  int 21h      ;◄■■ RETURNS AL=0 : NO KEY PRESSED, AL!=0 : KEY PRESSED.
  cmp al, 0
  je  move_snake
;PROCESS KEY.        
  mov ah, 0
  int 16h      ;◄■■ GET THE KEY.
move_snake:

  jmp game
```

Full example (no snake, of course)  :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax
game:
;CHECK IF KEY WAS PRESSED.
  mov ah, 0bh
  int 21h  
  cmp al, 0
  je  move_snake
;PROCESS KEY.        
  mov ah, 0
  int 16h
  mov ah, 2
  mov dl, al
  int 21h       ;◄■■ DISPLAY PRESSED KEY.
move_snake:
  mov ah, 2
  mov dl, '.'
  int 21h       ;◄■■ DISPLAY SOMETHING.
  jmp game

  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h
```